# Could you modify a file from a game in this manner?

Tags: usb, sublime-text-2, xbox360, code

What I am about to ask is probably going to sound like science fiction, but if I grab a usb, hook it up to my xbox and copy (for example) madden 15 to it. Then I plug it into my computer and open it with notepad or sublime text etc.. then I change my (for example) coins to 50 million. 
1. Is that possible?
2. What stops people from doing it?
3. Am I just completely insane?

Comment: "Change my coins to 50 million" I meant go in and look for where it says my coins and just edit it.

Comment: Related: [Why does an exe file not appear as ones and zeros in a text editor such as Notepad?](http://superuser.com/q/693440/194694)

Comment: Your not going to be able to modify a xbox save file on your pc for variety of reasons.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to edit save game files in the manner you describe. Yes, people are doing it. Some games encrypt the files or add checksums to make it harder. Some games keep their saves online instead of on the device.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks! (I always wondered if you could do it)